# Intel SIMD instructions speedup

Tags: c++, performance, intel, simd

I have the following code:

```
long a[1000];
long b[1000];
long c[1000];
long d[1000];
long e[10000000];

double start, end;
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    a[i] = i;
    b[i] = i*2;
    c[i] = i%13;
}
start = clock();
for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++){
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
            a[i] *= a[i];
            b[i] *= b[i];
            c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
            d[i] = a[i] * c[i];
        }

    }
    e[0] += a[k];
}
end = clock();
cout << end-start <<"\t"<< e[0];
```

Test configuration: intel core i7-4702MQ CPU, Haswell (As far as I know, my processor support AVX-II), intel c++ compiler v.14, visual studio 2013, Windows 8.1.

When I run the shown code, i get the time 3403 ms, If i add #pragma novetor, then time is  6934 ms, i.e. speedup is only 2 times. But if i change the type of all arrays to double, then time is 2067 ms and 7479 ms, respectively, i.e. SIMD-speedup is more than 3.5 times. Why is this happening? Why with integer types such small speedup?

Comment: What compiler options are you using? You need to actually tell ICC to use AVX2. (or host)

Comment: Oh, it's probably because the integer version vectorizes to `vpmulld` which is slow on Haswell. Haswell can run only 1 `vpmulld` every two cycles, but it can run 2 `vmulpd` every cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Because the vector operations (which the `#pragma novector` precludes) are designed for floating-point values.  If you are using integers, you add the steps of converting between the two types.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand. Here is a list of AVX-2-instructions https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide, which include operations with packed integers (_mm256_add_epi32, __m256i _mm256_mul_epi32, etc.).

Comment: It is not that they *can't* work with integers, but rather that they work better with floating-point values.

Answer (score 0):

When allowing for vectorization, the double precision implementations uses fma instruction and vmulpd, which has a throughput of 0.5.

[image: profiling double precision]

When using integer arithmetic, it makes use of vpmulld which has a throughput of 1 (half the performance).

[image: profiling integer]

However, I cannot reproduce the performances you mention.

- With vectorization - double: 4.76 seconds ; int: 3.04 seconds
- Without vectorization - double: 18.2 seconds ; int: 17.8 seconds

The scalar performance drop can be easily explained in double as the compiler uses the scalar versions of the same instructions, however, for integer, it uses `imul` instruction.

*Results obtained on a i7-4712MQ with Intel C++ 16.0, x64 compilation.* **single threaded**

You may say it is just an x6 improvement for int, why not a x8. Well, in multithread, the performance of the int version is 2.6 times better than the double precision. It might be that latency of various instructions is much better covered by the processor thanks to hyper-threading, or cache behavior as sizes differ.